# Undefined variable error in view in Laravel 5.5.13

Tags: laravel, variables, view

I get below error when I run my code. what's wrong?

```
Undefined variable: tasks (View: C:\Users\Silvercover\blog\resources\views\Pages\home.blade.php)
```

here is my controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function home() {
        $tasks = ['Jack','Sara'];
        return view("Pages.home")->with(compact($tasks));
    }
}
```

and this is my view:

```
@extends('Layout.layout')
<h3>Names:</h3>
<hr>
@foreach ($tasks as $task)
    {{$task}}
@endforeach
```

I am using Laravel 5.5.13.

Comment: `->with(["tasks" => $tasks])` would solve that. I see the `compact()` function used lots of places, but I'm not familiar with the correct syntax to use with it.

Comment: @TimLewis No it doesn't help.

Comment: Yes it does lol. I use that syntax daily with no issue. Regardless though, read up https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#passing-data-to-views and see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Can you try changing `->with(["tasks" => $tasks])` to `->with(array('tasks' => $tasks))`?! See if it helps.

Comment: why would changing the array syntax help at all. this is PHP 7.

Answer (score -1):

Do this:

return view("Pages.home",compact('tasks'));

OR

The with() method only asks you to send the name of the variable, not the variable itself:

return view("Pages.home")->with('tasks');

in case there are multiple variables send them using array:

return view("Pages.home",compact(['tasks', 'otherVariable', 'anotherOne']));

OR

return view("Pages.home")->with(['tasks', 'otherVariable', 'anotherOne']);

Comment: `with` needs the name and the value. `view(...)->with('somevar', 'somevalue');` unless you are passing a key value array as the first argument to `with`.